# Unable to copy data of intersecting row and column to another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to copy data from one sheet to another using index and match as i want specific data of intersecting rows and column.

i have attached the sheet where sheet 1 is source sheet and sheet 2 is destination. i want in cell value(C7) of sheet 1 and Cell value(B2) of sheet 2 same.I am using index match function but its returning department value.

`=INDEX(Sheet1!A3:H15,MATCH(Sheet1!A7,Sheet1!A3:A15,0),MATCH(Sheet1!C3,Sheet1!C3:H3,0))`

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YuIbG1tDQ9tp1k5OrZ8slP1PUCjG4vsRsAVLZbt8Wyw/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Your second match range is less than the table width.  Change C3:H3  to A3:H3 and you may get the result you want.

I find it helpful when doing multiple MATCH functions to break them out into a scratch area on the spread sheet and examine them separately.  Then combine the correct formulae into the single cell formula.